# Is it possible to connect a ublox NEO-6Q GPS directly to a Raspberry Pi 2B?

Tags: pi-2, gps

I would like to know if it is possible to directly connect the [ublox NEO-6Q GPS](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/neo-6-series) with the Raspberry Pi 2B.

I have found videos of people connecting the GPS to a raspberry pi but they use a module to do it.

Is it possible to directly connect, or do I have to use some kind of module to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GPS chip directly, but you will need to do a lot of micro-soldering to get all the connections done on the chip. If you are not experienced at soldering, you can easily damage or destroy the chip with the heat from soldering. A module has the soldering part already done for you, and you only have 4 electrical connections to make to the Raspberry Pi with jumper cables that you just press in.
If you really want to be soldering this chip, [here](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_%28GPS.G6-HW-09005%29.pdf) is the datasheet for it. Pin assignments are on pages 12 and 13.

Comment: Just for clarity: There are 12 connections along the longest edge of that chip, which is about the width of my index finger (16mm). It's *just about* feasible to solder to those, but it's not a lot of fun. +1 for 'buy a breakout board'.